# If I am an admin of a WiFi router can I learn the password when it gets change by other admin?

Tags: network, password-management, wifi

I have a Huawei WS319 router. The admin password is known to me and my friend.

Is there any way to learn WiFi password (through automatic notification) if it gets changed in the future, given that I have full access as admin?

Comment: this is really router-dependent

Comment: mayur - can you clarify whether you're looking for a general process to share administrative responsibilities from a friend, or defending against a "friend" that is acting maliciously?

Comment: If your friend changes the password, ask him what the new one is. If he doesn't tell you, then he may no longer be your friend! At that point you would have to physically reset the router to gain access again.

Comment: i just asked if there any way.. i expect technical answer..

Comment: @mayur the technical answer will depend on the router model. You will have to look at your router's documentation or contact their support.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to find a secure channel to exchange the new password over. Communicating verbally would work just fine. As to an automatic notification, the only way to do this would be to flash your router with custom firmware which would allow you to write scripts to add functionality, such as DD-WRT. However, DD-WRT is unsupported on the Huawei WS319. As always, flashing the firmware on the router runs the risk of bricking it, so ensure that the firmware is compatible before flashing it.

Comment: My assumption is that the OP is trying to defend against an antagonist changing the password underneath him. So options like verbal communication are out of scope for the question.

Comment: My assumption was based OP's statement "The admin password is known to me and my friend." That makes more sense, though. I see no reason to notify unless it was changed by an unauthorized party.